# How to set CRON job in PHP

Tags: php, cron

I am new in cron job. I want to know how can I set cron job in PHP?
we should create cron job for cPanel ? if no then what is the procedure

Comment: It depends on your OS / what systems you are using, but you're not the first person to want to setup a cron job, so you'll most likely find a nifty tutorial on google.

Comment: did you have ssh access ?

Comment: @ I have ftp and only phpmyadmin details ( not cpanel )

Comment: Have you got a cPanel installed, and do you have access to it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't set up cron jobs in PHP (well you could but thats a whole different game).

Look into `crontab` for how to set it up.

Seeing as you are using cPanel, it has a nice interface for you to set up these "automated tasks"...

Comment: you mean, we need cpanel detail for set up cron job ? and without cpanel we cant do that. right ?

Comment: I meant, if you have cpanel then you should use it to set up your cron jobs.

You can also do them via the command line (crontab) but sounds like you dont have access to that either... youre going to need access to one of them if you are to set up cron jobs...

Answer (score 0):

if you cann't use cPanel cron jobs but need something like that, then you can use `ignore_user_abort(true)` with `set_time_limit(0)` function for run the script in background. but remember that those function will run the script forever if you don't stop it within your script.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php